# Why do some compilers generate direct machine code?

Tags: computer-science, compiler, assembly

I was taking this course - [CMU 18-447, Computer Architecture at Carnegie Mellon](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5PHm2jkkXmidJOd59REog9jDnPDTG6IJ) to brush my knowledge and concepts.

They say that most of the machine level details and implementations are taken care of at the Instruction Set Architecture(ISA) level and is abstracted at that level.

Some Intel processors even have hardware level translation layers that take the front level ISA that is exposed to the programmer and translate them further closer to the machine.

Given such power is provided by the ISA/Processor itself, why do compilers generate direct machine code, or is it just a black box and internally it uses assemblers to convert them into direct machine code?

I hear that JVM takes byte code and translate them directly to machine code(exe).Is this true or is my understanding wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find [this definition](http://homedir.jct.ac.il/~citron/ca/isa.html) pretty clear:

> The Instruction Set Architecture (ISA) is the part of the processor that is visible to the programmer or compiler writer. The ISA serves as the boundary between software and hardware.

The ISA provides an abstraction of the actual [microarchitecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microarchitecture), which is the implementation of the instruction set by the processor.

So when your compiler is said to produce machine code, it produces instructions for the configured [instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set), not the actual processor, so any processor implementing that instruction set can run that machine code.

A virtual machine such as the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) or [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) runs code that has been compiled to bytecode specific to that virtual machine's architecture, [Java bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) and [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) in this case.

The runtime of such a virtual machine, which in turn is built for and runs on a specific processor architecture and OS, translates the bytecode to the machine code and API calls for the platform it runs on, and usually does so [just-in-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation).

Comment: @Greedy correct. The JVM executes `.jar`s for example, which contain Java bytecode. The Java source code has already been compiled to this bytecode, the JVM will transform/compile the bytecode into machine code. See [Machine code (Wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) and [Assembly code vs Machine code vs Object code? (SO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466790/assembly-code-vs-machine-code-vs-object-code).

Comment: Hmm.Makes some sense now.Traditional compilers take that route and ones like bytecode/IL gets directly executed to machine code.So the runtimes for JVM/CLR are optimized to produce efficient machine code rather than produce optimized assembly?

Comment: @Greedy please see the links in my comment, I think  _"Assembly code is plain-text and (somewhat) human read-able source code that has a mostly direct 1:1 analog with machine instructions"_ is relevant to your question.

Comment: I was editing my comment when you posted,sorry for that.Thanks for clearing this up,I now have a better picture of things :)

Answer (score 5):

> Some Intel processors even have hardware level translation layers that take the front level ISA that is exposed to the programmer and translate them further closer to the machine.

That concept is called [microprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode) and has been around in theory since Charles Babbage and in implementation since the 1960s.  Some processors aren't microprogrammed at all and use hardware to execute the instructions, others are entirely microprogrammed and some take a hybrid approach depending on what instruction is being executed.

> Given such power is provided by the ISA/Processor itself...

That power *exists* in the processor but isn't *provided*.  The API for a processor is its instruction set.  The microprogramming, if there is any, is an implementation detail that you're not supposed to know or care about.

> ... why do compilers generate direct machine code, or is it just a black box and internally it uses assemblers to convert them into direct machine code?

I'm sure there are a few compilers that directly generate object code, but most generate assembly and then assemble it behind the scenes.  Assembly is just a human-readable longhand for the corresponding object code that's a lot easier to generate and use for debugging or just understanding what the compiler produces.  Odds are very good that if you're writing a compiler for a target, you'll already have a perfectly serviceable assembler (or cross-assembler) that's preferable to use over re-inventing that wheel yourself.

> I hear that JVM takes byte code and translate them directly to machine code(exe).Is this true or is my understanding wrong here?

Early versions of the JVM were, essentially, emulators that would examine each bytecode instruction and carry out the operations needed.  This is very similar to what microcode does, just implemented in software on a general-purpose computer.  Early JVMs were also very slow, which led to the use of things like just-in-time compilation of bytecode to native instructions.

None of this matters, though, because the *lingua franca* for Java is Java bytecode.  This is no different than the instruction set on a real CPU in that you don't care how it's implemented under the covers.  There are, in fact, a number of CPUs called "Java processors" that can run Java bytecode directly, a variant of the ARM9 being one of them.  Java software won't know or care if it's being run on a Java Processor or JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers may output assembly code, linkable object code, or ready-to-run machine code; I've worked with examples of all three types.  Although compilers which output assembly code may be more adaptable to different platforms than those which output object code, outputting assembly code is often slower than outputting machine code, and running a program will require the assembly code undergo further processing steps.  It really isn't much harder for a compiler to generate machine code than to generate assembly code; in some cases it may be easier.

As for whether to generate linkable or ready-to-run code, it's often faster and easier for a compiler to produce the latter; the only advantage of producing the former is that building a program will require recompiling only the parts that have changed, and then linking everything, versus having to feed everything through the compiler.  If projects will generally be large, and the portion that changes on any given build small, then being able to selectively compile the parts of the code that have changed may be a 'win'.  If, however, one is apt to want to rebuild most of the program on each build, producing runnable machine code may be faster than going through an intermediate link stage.

An additional benefit of producing runnable machine code is that a compiler may be able to take advantage of things it knows about the locations of objects in ways that would not be possible when generating relocatable code.  For example, if `foo` and `bar` are declared in separate modules, a statement `foo=bar;` would require something like:

```
    ldr r0,[pc+(_addr_of_bar-*)]
    ldr r1,[pc+(_addr_of_foo-*)]
    ldr r2,[r0]
    str r2,[r1]
 ...somewhere within 2K of the above:
 _addr_of_bar: dw _bar
 _addr_of_foo: dw _foo
```

If variables `foo` and `bar` happen to be at known addresses which are within 4K of each other [e.g. 1600 bytes apart], the code could be simplified to something like:

```
    ldr r0,[pc+(_addr_of_foo_bar-*)]
    ldr r1,[r0+600]
    str r1,[r0-1000]
 ...somewhere within 2K of the above:
 _addr_of_foo_bar: dw _foo+1000
```

Such optimizations are only possible if the compiler knows how things are going to be placed.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that some compilers are indeed generating directly machine code, and some of them are even generating machine code in the same process that is running the compiler (a typical example of that last case is the [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) implementation of Common Lisp: every time you interactively type some expression in its [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), it is getting translated to *machine code* then executed).

Other compilers are generating some other form of code. That could be [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) (containing notably a mix of [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) with relocation directives for the linker), [assembler code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language), etc... It is not unusual for a compiler to [emit C code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257868/when-does-it-make-sense-to-compile-my-own-language-to-c-code-first/257873#257873) (which is further compiled by some *existing* C compiler).

The "[object code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_code)" terminology may be ambiguous: I use it for the output form of any compiler (so C++ code could be object code for me, in a compiler translating *to* C++). Some people are restricting "object code" to object files (e.g. [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) files with relocation info).

Read more about [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) (consider using some JIT libraries like [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit), [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit), ...) and [optimizing compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler).

The interesting thing today is that computers are fast enough today to make the following scenario reasonable: you code a compiler to C, and an interactive REPL which reads some expression, compile it to C code (often a few hundred of lines), forks a compilation of that generated C code into a plugin, then finally [dynamically loads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) that generated plugin (using [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) ...) is fast enough to be acceptable by your user.

Notice also that optimization is more and more required (to take advantage of current processors) and that it is much more costly than emitting C -or assembler- code and tranlating that. (If you generate C code, you leverage on the optimization abilities of your C compiler).