# When does it make sense to compile my own language to C code first?

Tags: programming-languages, c, language-design, compiler, syntax

When designing an own programming language, when does it make sense to write a converter that takes the source code and converts it to C or C++ code so that I can use an existing compiler like gcc to end up with machine code? Are there projects that use this approach?

Comment: What do you mean by "does it make sense?"  Yes, this approach is sometimes used.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Let me reframe the question slightly. When does it make sense?

Comment: http://yosefk.com/blog/c-as-an-intermediate-language.htmlv

Comment: What's your use case? Why do you want to create a programming language of your own in the first place? What makes existing languages insufficient or sub-optimal for the task?

Comment: If you look past C you'll see that C# and Java also both compile to intermediate languages.  You're saved from having to redo a lot of work that someone else has already done by targeting an intermediate language instead of going straight to assembly.

Comment: @emodendroket However, C# and Java compile to an IL that is designed to be an IL in general and for C#/Java specifically, so in many ways CIL and JVM bytecode are more sensible and convenient as an IL than C could ever be. It's not about whether to use any intermediate language, it's about which intermediate language to use.

Comment: @delnan Well, it's not really clear from the OP which thing it's "about," but, sure, there are various reasons you might pick one or the other to be your intermediate language once you decide you want one.

Comment: @Tom It would be for learning purpose mainly and I haven't decided at all yet. I would try to simplify C++ syntax to be similar to Python while preserving all the compile time features.

Comment: @emodendroket Microsoft is [using their C++ compiler backend](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/04/02/announcing-net-native-preview.aspx) to compile C# IL into machine code themselves now. The OP would be advised to skip the middleman.

Comment: It makes sense when your language semantics maps to C easily (e.g., you do not require a runtime with preemptive green threads, like Erlang), when you do not care about compilation latency (e.g., this is not a scripting or protocol language), and when you can trust C level to optimise your code (e.g., no need to hint backend any further).

Comment: Look at several free software implementations generating C code. And I hope you'll make your language implementation free software.

Comment: @SK-logic Basically I want to simplify the syntax of C++. So it won't be interpreted, but compilation time is still a concern.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's not that I think of it as more as a learning project. However, I'll make it open source of course.

Comment: If you want to make a C++ like language, better emit C code (than C++ code). And there have been many attempts doing that (recently, Vala).

Comment: But think about garbage collection (or the lack of it) before starting to code!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch My intend is not to add complicated language features, but to simplify the syntax to make it more useful for prototyping. Therefore, I think compiling to C++ is the better choice for this specific requirement. Moreover, I get all the features like classes, templates and more on top.

Comment: I am not sure at all. I believe that compiling to C could be simpler for an object-oriented extension of C. BTW, you should write some blog entry, or some public document -perhaps on `github`, describing your current ideas (even if you did not start coding your translator) I'm sure you'll get interesting comments and feedback.

Comment: Here is the updated link from @RobertHarvey's comment: https://yosefk.com/blog/c-as-an-intermediate-language.html.

Comment: Note that javascript is being established as the new common tongue due to it being the assembly language of browsers.  It may make sense to consider Javascript as a backend too.

Comment: Also note that C was designed as portable assembly languages on the many different architectures back then.  Today you can do with x86_64 (and ARM and x86 if you really want)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Tranlating to C code is a very well established habit. The original C with classes (and the early C++ implementations, then called [Cfront](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront)) did that successfully. Several implementations of Lisp or Scheme are doing that, e.g. [Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org/), [Scheme48](http://s48.org/), [Bigloo](http://www-sop.inria.fr/indes/fp/Bigloo/). Some people translated [Prolog to C](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fclip.dia.fi.upm.es%2Fpapers%2Fmorales03%3Ap-to-c-ciclops.pdf). And so did some versions of [Mozart](https://mozart.github.io/) (and there have been attempts to compile [Ocaml bytecode to C](https://github.com/ocaml-bytes/ocamlcc)). J.Pitrat's artificial intelligence [CAIA system](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2014/04/caia-my-colleague/) is also bootstrapped and generates all its C code. [Vala](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala) also translates to C, for GTK related code. Queinnec's book [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) have some chapter about translation to C.

One of the issues when translating to C is [tail-recursive calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). The C standard does not guarantee that a C compiler is translating them properly (to a "jump with arguments", i.e. *without* eating call stack), even if in *some* cases, recent versions of GCC (or of Clang/LLVM) do that optimization.

Another issue is [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection). Several implementations just use the [Boehm conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) (which is *C friendly*...). If you wanted to garbage collect code (like several Lisp implementations do, e.g. SBCL) that might be a nightmare (you would like to [`dlclose`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dlclose.html) on Posix).

Yet another issue is dealing with first-class [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) and [call/cc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation). But clever tricks are possible (look inside Chicken Scheme). Accessing the call-stack could require a lot of tricks (but see [GNU backtrace](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html), and [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) etc....). Orthogonal [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29) of continuations (i.e. of stacks or threads) would be difficult in C.

Exception handling is often a matter to emit clever calls to [longjmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h) etc...

You may want to generate (in your emitted C code) appropriate `#line` directives. This is boring and takes a lot of work (you'll want that to e.g. produce more easily `gdb`-debuggable code).

My obsolete [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) lispy domain specific language (to customize or extend [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) is translated to C (actually to poor C++ now). It has its own generational copying garbage collector. (You might be interested by [Qish](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/qishintro.html) or [Ravenbrook MPS](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/)). Actually, generational GC is easier in machine generated C code than in hand-written C code (because you'll tailor your C code generator for your write-barrier and GC machinery). The [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) static source code analyzer (described in [this **DRAFT**](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report) also generates C code.

I don't know any language implementation translating to *genuine* C++ code, i.e. using some "compile-time garbage collection" technique to emit C++ code using a lot of STL templates and respecting the [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom. (please tell if you know one). But [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) aims to generate C++ code (or C code, perhaps also machine code).

What is funny today is that (on current Linux desktops) C compilers may be fast enough to implement an interactive top level [read-eval-print-loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) translated to C: you'll emit C code (a few hundred lines) at every user interaction, you'll `fork` a compilation of it into a shared object, which you would then `dlopen`. (MELT is doing that all ready, and it is usually fast enough). All this might take a few tenths of a second and be acceptable by end-users.

When possible, I would recommend translating to C, not to C++, in particular because C++ compilation is slow. However, C++ has today powerful standard [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), [exceptions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions),  [λ-expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), etc .... and is used or required by interesting C++ libraries or frameworks such as [Qt](https://qt.io/), [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/), [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), and all these features is what motivates the choice of generating C++ code in a pet project of mine called [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/). If generating C++ dynamically, either accept to wait more than a second for compiling every generated C++ file (e.g. into a temporary [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29), see for Linux the [C++ dlopen mini howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/)) or use clever tricks (e.g. [ccache](https://ccache.dev/) and/or [GCC pre-compiled headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html), etc....) while minimizing if possible the total amount of `#include`-d material) to decrease the C++ compilation time.

If you are implementing your language, you might also consider (instead of emitting C code) some [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) libraries like [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), GNU [lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit), or even [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) or [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/). If you want to translate to C, you might *sometimes* use [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler): it compiles very quickly the generated C code (even in memory) to *slow* machine code. But in general you want to take advantage of the [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) done by a  real C compiler like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

If you translate to C your language, be sure to build the entire [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of the generated C code in memory first (this also makes easier to generate first all the declarations, then all the definitions and function code). You would be able to do some optimizations/normalizations this way. Also, you could be interested in several [GCC extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html) (e.g. computed gotos). You'll probably want to avoid generating *huge* C functions - e.g. of a hundred thousands line of generated C - (you'll better split them into smaller pieces) since optimizing C compilers are very unhappy with very big C functions (in practice, and experimentally, `gcc -O` compilation time of large functions is proportional to the square of the function code size). So limit the size of your generated C functions to a few thousand lines each.

Notice that both [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) (thru [LLVM](http://llvm.org/)) and [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (thru [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/)) C & C++ compilers offer some way to emit some internal representations suited for these compilers, but doing so might (or not) be harder than emitting C (or C++) code, and is specific to each compiler.
Also, recent GCC are extensible thru [dlopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)-ed [plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html).

If designing a language to be translated to C, you probably want to have several tricks (or constructs) to generate a mixture of C with your language. My DSL2011 paper [*MELT:*  a Translated Domain Specific Language
Embedded in the GCC Compiler](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/MELT-Starynkevitch-DSL2011.pdf) should give you useful hints.

Generating C code might be done with [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) (like [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) does). But you could also consider using [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [Bigloo](http://www-sop.inria.fr/indes/fp/Bigloo/), [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/), [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/), [Python](https://python.org/), [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp), etc... when coding your own C code generator.

Comment: Are you referring to "Chicken Scheme?"

Comment: Yes.I gave the URL.

Comment: Is it relatively practical to make a virtual machine, like Java or something, compile bytecode to C, then use gcc for JIT compilation?  Or should they just go straight from bytecode to assembly?

Comment: @Panzercrisis Most JIT compilers require their machine code backends to support things like replacing a function and patching existing code with a jump/trap door. Aside from that, gcc specifically is... architecturally less suited to JIT compilation and other use cases. Check out libgccjit though: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-10/msg00228.html and https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/JIT

Comment: Tail recursion is just `goto` function entry. But mutual recursion...

Comment: It is a goto with argument passing...

Comment: Beautiful answer.  I would have added some further links to fundamental papers of Dan Friedman (to different related topics) and to the old library.scheme.org which now lies here: https://web.archive.org/web/20180721161229/http://library.readscheme.org/index.html

Answer (score 9):

It makes sense when the time to generate full machine code outweighs the inconvenience of having an intermediate step of compiling your "IL" into machine code using a C compiler.

Typically domain-specific languages are written in this way, a very high level system is used to define or describe a process that is then compiled into an executable or dll. The time taken to produce working/good assembly is much greater than generating C, and C is quite close the assembly code for performance, so it makes good sense to generate C and re-use the skills of the C compiler writers. Note that it isn't just compiling, but optimising too - the guys who write gcc or llvm have spent a lot of time making optimised machine code, it'd be daft to try to reinvent all their hard work.

It might be more acceptbale to re-use LLVM's compiler backend which IIRC is language neutral, so you generate LLVM instructions instead of C code.

Comment: Seems like libraries are a pretty compelling reason to consider it too.

Comment: When you say "your 'IL'", what are you referring to?  An Abstract Syntax Tree?

Comment: @RobertHarvey no, I mean C code. In the OPs case, this is an Intermediate Language halfway between his own high-level language and machine code. I put it in quotes to try and convey this idea that its not IL as used by many people (ie Microsoft's .NET IL for example)

Answer (score 2):

Writing a compiler to produce machine code may not be much more difficult than writing one which produces C (in some cases it may be easier), but a compiler which produces machine code will only be able to produce runnable programs on the particular platform for which it was written; a compiler that produces C code, by contrast, may be able to produce program for any platform which uses a dialect of C which the generated code is designed to support.  Note that in many cases it may be possible to write C code which is completely portable and which will behave as desired without using any behaviors not guaranteed by the C standard, but code which relies upon platform-guaranteed behaviors may be able to run much faster on platforms which make those guarantees than code which does not.

For example, suppose a language supports a feature to yield a `UInt32` from four consecutive bytes of an arbitrarily-aligned `UInt8[]`, interpreted in big-endian fashion.  On some compilers, one could write the code as:

```
uint32_t dat = *(__packed uint32_t*)p;
return (dat >> 24) | (dat >> 8) | ((uint32_t)dat << 8) | ((uint32_t)dat << 24));
```

and have the compiler generate a word-load operation followed by a reverse-bytes-in-word instruction.  Some compilers, however, would not support the __packed modifier and in its absence would generate code that wouldn't work.

Alternatively, one could write the code as:

```
return dat[3] | ((uint16_t)dat[2] << 8) | ((uint32_t)dat[1] << 16) | ((uint32_t)dat[0] << 24);
```

such a code should work on any platform, even those where `CHAR_BITS` isn't 8 (assuming that each octet of source data ended up in a distinct array element), but such code may likely not run nearly as fast as the would the non-portable version on platforms supporting the former.

Note that portability often requires that code be extremely liberal with typecasts and similar constructs.  For example, code which wants to multiply two 32-bit unsigned integers and yield the lower 32 bits of the result must for portability be written as:

```
uint32_t result = 1u*x*y;
```

Without that `1u`, a compiler on a system where INT_BITS ranged from 33 to 64 could legitimately do anything it wanted if the product of x and y was larger than 2,147,483,647, and some compilers are prone to take advantage of such opportunities.

Answer (score 1):

You have some excellent answers above but given that, in a comment, you answered the question "Why do you want to create a programming language of your own in the first place? " with "It would be for learning purpose mainly," I'm going to answer from a different angle.

It makes sense to write a converter that takes the source code and converts it to C or C++ code, so that you can use an existing compiler like gcc to end up with machine code, if you are more interested in learning about lexical, syntax and semantic analysis than you are in learning about code generation and optimization!

Writing your own machine code generator is a pretty significant piece of work which you can avoid by compiling to C code, if it's not what you are primarily interested in!

If, however, you are into assembly program and fascinated by the challenges of optimizing code at the lowest level, then by all means, write a code generator yourself for the learning experience!

Answer (score -7):

It depends on what Operating System you are using if you are using Windows there is a Microsoft IL (Intermediate Language) Which converts your code into intermediate language so that it takes no time to get compiled into machine code. Or If you are using Linux there is a separate compiler for that

Coming back to your question is when you when designing your own language you should have a separate compiler or interpreter for that because machine does not know the high level language . Your code should be compiled into machine code to make it useful for machine

Comment: `Your code should be compiled into machine code to make it useful for machine` -- If your compiler produced c code as an output, you could put the c code into a c compiler to produce machine code, right?

Comment: yes. because machine doesn't the c language

Comment: Right.  So the question was "When does it make sense to emit c and use a c compiler, rather than emitting machine language or byte code directly?"

Comment: actually he asking to design his programming language in which he is asking that "converts it to C or C++ code" . So i am explaining this if your are designing your own programming language why you should use the c compiler or c++. if you are intelligent enough you should design your own

Comment: I don't think you understand the question.  See http://yosefk.com/blog/c-as-an-intermediate-language.html