# Does a Completely Full-Featured Intermediate Language Exist?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, language-features, language-choice

Often when translating between languages (whether with program translation or compiling) it's a one-way, destructive translation.  The functionality of the "port" isn't lost, but some of the intent and expression is.

For instance, porting a program from Java to C is possible, but you lose the notion of classes and methods.  If that program were to be ported back to Java you'd need to infer the intent of what would be considered an object to get back to the original state.  And that's something that a computer isn't good at doing.  As such you'd end up with a Java program that looked more like a C program with data structures and a big collection of static functions.

Also consider a compiler.  Once a language has been compiled down to assembler or even to say CIL or JVM, concepts such as if statements are lost as they are turned into branches.

On a higher level, source to source translators exist, but some languages have features (i.e. delegates in C#) which don't exist in other languages (like Java not having delegates).  The translation can happen, but is mildly destructive (i.e. Java would need a wrapper class to simulate delegates).

So, having said all that, is there a language who's goal is to be structurally compatible with all other languages by supporting all language features of all languages?

I'm not so concerned with being able to fully translate between languages as I am with being able to express each language's code in the common language.  So the goal would be translating to the common language and back again to the source language without losing anything.  Like: Java->Common->Java or LISP->Common->LISP

Comment: see [Are non Turing-complete languages considered programming languages at all?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/172979/are-non-turing-complete-languages-considered-programming-languages-at-all) and [Measure of power other than Turing completeness](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/812/measure-of-power-other-than-turing-completeness)

Comment: @gnat I don't see how this relates to Turing-completeness.  I'm not interested in the translation process, just the one common language.

Comment: Okay, maybe you could create a common intermediate language for  few of them most popular languages. But where do you stop? At Haskell? At all of its extensions? At [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29)? At [INTRECAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL)? At [Malbolge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbolge)? And would you keep updating your common intermediate language forever, as new languages are developed (and old ones updated)?

Comment: Also, you didn't answer the most important question: **Why?** What would be the point of such language existing, if the only thing it could do well would be to get back the code you already had?

Comment: @svick I think at some point you'll hit a critical mass where all language features are supported.  The common language doesn't have to support all language *syntax*, just features.  Enough that you could trivially rebuild the syntax for the source language.

Comment: @svick Why?  You could unify code projects easier for one.  Though "Why?" is a different question, I'm just curious if such a thing exists.

Comment: @rwong I'm not sure any lowering would need to take place.

Comment: It can't exist. Trivially: a language with a finitely long specification must support finitely many features in it. Then, you can invent one which does not. For example, language FooBarBaz, that I just made up, does something special if the MD5 hash of the source file ends in a 5. Does your intermediate language support that flag? Probably not. If it does support that flag, then I just have to find another flag which it doesn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Once a language has been compiled down to assembler or even to say CIL or JVM, concepts such as if statements are lost as they are turned into branches.

Not particularly in practice. If you look at a tool like [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), it will happily turn CIL back into pretty accurate C# code, ifs and all.

> So, having said all that, is there a language who's goal is to be structurally compatible with all other languages by supporting all language features of all languages?

No, because at that point we wouldn't ***need*** compilers or source translators since we have the One True Language. Sarcasm aside, this is effectively asking why we have different languages in the first place. Language features are not things that live in isolation. Providing one often hinders (or breaks) others. If there was a language that could provide the features of others without loss, why would we be using the others?

Comment: `If you look at a tool like Reflector, it will happily turn CIL back into pretty accurate C# code, ifs and all.` -- That's because CIL includes a substantial amount of metadata that helps reconstruct the original C#, including identifiers.  This is not generally true of languages like C, whose compile process is *lossy.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey - sure, but even "substantial amount of metadata" isn't "100% of the information contained in the source language".

Comment: Which is why Reflector isn't 100% accurate at reproducing the original source code.

Comment: That's not quite the same question because there are some features we clearly *don't* want, like COMEFROM.

Comment: @DeadMG: That's a trivial case; most of the time, language design is far more involved than that, and deals not with misfeatures but with features that are not quite good enough, or that have some wart that has a particularly unfortunate reaction with some other minor feature in the language, or the like. Look up, say, Eric Lippert's writings for a good idea of all the tradeoffs. Or Jonathan Shapiro's, if you want a less mainstream approach.

Comment: Telastyn, Can you give an example of one feature breaking another?  Where the two features couldn't exist in parallel with each other?  I'm not sure it's as common as you say.  There are language choices, for sure, but everything compiles down to the same machine language at some point.

Comment: @SamWashburn - consider Erlang's concurrency model vs mutable state.

Comment: Concurrency is a good point.  However, what about multiple concurrency options depending on how you code?  As horrible as that sounds from a "pure language" vantage point, wouldn't that still work?  Almost like using OpenCL with C.  The GPU parts are massively parallel but the mutable C parts are full of semaphores.

Comment: @SamWashburn - `However, what about multiple concurrency options depending on how you code?` And how would this language know what concurrency options can be used with the various semantic options available?

Comment: By specifying it?  Maybe the Erlang to Common translator specifies the type of concurrency to use.

Comment: @SamWashburn - And what happens when you need to encode Scala's specific concurrency semantics, or some new language you've never heard of. You're missing the point. You're asking why there is no informational superset of all languages. [There can be no such thing.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox)

Comment: @Telastyn I don't see how Russell's paradox applies.  This isn't a superset of all conceivable languages past-present-future, just all the ones currently implemented in the common language.  If a new language is developed, you add any of it's unique features to the common language.  And the common language exists as the superset and is not included in the set.  I.e. the barber doesn't shave.  Where's the paradox?

Comment: @SamWashburn - I suppose it doesn't since the common language isn't executable. Still, I don't see how a language that defines all of the unique semantics of languages in such an iterative way is going to be any more common or useful than having a bunch of source files with different extensions denoting the language they're written in. Anyways, if you're so deadset on your idea, go do it and prove me wrong.

Comment: @Telastyn I just may. :)  But either way, you're right, it doesn't currently exist.  Thanks for the good discussion.

Comment: @Nathan: Of course it's a simple example, but it proves the point and there's no need for a more complex one.

Answer (score 5):

Some intermediate languages have been successfully used as target for a lot of various languages, e.g. [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) (or Ramsey & Jones' [C--](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C--), which might be a dead project in 2015).

Notice that an intermediate language does not carry all the information provided in the source language (e.g. you are losing information when compiling from C to LLVM).

However, I am not sure that your wish makes sense. There are some programming language features which are *not* compositional, or are a whole program thing. Eg [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) (you can't implement [call/cc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation) without some support from your intermediate language), [exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling), or even [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) or parallelism or [homoiconicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) or [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)) or [threads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) (or [concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science))).

Notice that for your question programming language [semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_%28computer_science%29) matter much more than syntax. Of course, all these intermediate representations are theoretically [Turing-equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) e.g. to a [RAM machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine).

BTW, some people might believe that [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) machine code or [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) is actually what you want....

In 2020  consider also [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [Gimple](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) or even generating C code. See of course [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) and [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/). In [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) we want to generate C++ code

Comment: IIRC C-- is targeted by Haskell

Comment: AFAIK *C--* **was** targeted by Haskell.

Comment: Well, you could certainly implement exceptions based on normal call/return. Of course, the normal program flow is no longer favored all that much.

Comment: You can simulate an x86-64 on a Turing machine. It has no call/return  and no call stack

Answer (score 2):

The only way for a conversion from language X to some intermediate language IL and back to be lossless is for IL to be a superset of X. If you want to have multiple languages as X, then IL has to be a superset of all of them.

Therefore, I would suggest that IL has the following structure:

```
delimiter: ---------SOMERANDOMSTRING----------
---------SOMERANDOMSTRING----------
language: C
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { printf("hello world\n"); return 0; }
---------SOMERANDOMSTRING----------
language: Java
public class Main { public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.stdout.println("hello world");
}}
---------SOMERANDOMSTRING----------
```

In other words, MIME-like embedding of the actual source code into the language. The "compiler" then has to parse apart the pieces and pass them to a proper processor for that language.

This obviously isn't useful.

Comment: I mean lossless from a semantic standpoint.  The syntax can vary so long as the original language can be reconstructed in a "pretty print" fashion.  Do you still think this is the only solution?

Comment: @SamWashburn You'd have to have a language with every feature from every language, or at least features so powerful that they can represent every feature, along with annotations containing hint about what the original looked like. Such a language would be completely unusable for humans because of the learning curve involved, and the compiler would be incredibly massive. My solution is much easier to implement, even though it wasn't meant quite seriously.