# Do bytecode compilers compile syntax directly or intermediate assembly language?

Tags: compiler, virtual-machine, interpreters, bytecode

I am going to write a very simple VM and bytecode compiler. Is it typical for a bytecode compiler to read the syntax and attempt to create the bytecode directly or is there an intermediate stage to make the process easier to understand?

If I do compiler -> bytecode - it should be a less tedious process, but maybe more difficult for me to understand while writing the program.

If I do compiler -> intermediate language -> bytecode - it should be simpler, but will take much more time because I have to write three programs.

Which is better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is Virtual Machine Bytecode?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/231054/what-exactly-is-virtual-machine-bytecode)

Comment: @gnat, no not really. The question is about compiler design.

Comment: The term "intermediate language" is inconvenient in this context because in the .NET world this is the resulting byte code. You mean an intermediate code expression format. In addition to Basile's answer, this may be useful: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/331253/how-is-a-abstract-syntax-tree-used-to-execute-source-code/331289#331289

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch this has been asked and answered too, in [How to write a very basic compiler](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/165543/how-to-write-a-very-basic-compiler)

Comment: @Synaps3: I am curious of what kind of compiler & bytecode you are thinking about? Is your implementation some free software available somewhere (I hope that yes). If you don't want to edit your question to improve it, feel free to send me some private email mentioning your question.

Comment: FYI, to be precise, the term "assembly language" usually implies a human-readable textual format intended to be run thru an assembler to generate object code containing machine code or machine language.  In the old days, a number of compilers did indeed generate assembly text files as output, then invoked the assembler.  However, most compilers (or JITs) these days do not involve assembly language, and instead generate machine code/language directly.

Comment: @ErikEidt: Even today [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is generating assembler files, and that does not matter performance wise, since the compilation time proper is a lot more (at least 10x, when you ask GCC to optimize with `-O1` or more) than the time spent in the assembler, which today is running very quickly.

Answer (score 10):

> If I do compiler -> intermediate language -> bytecode - it should be simpler, but will take much more time because I have to write three programs.

You don't need to write three *programs*, you just need to write three *modules* in the *same* compiler program (and these modules do *share* some data, so you want them in the same [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) & [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)). You might but probably *should not* organize your compiler as three separate *programs* (running in different processes which would communicate by some [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) such as [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) or [pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe)) but this approach is inconvenient and harder (unless your ambition is to explore the design of a concurrent compiler running on several cores or computers in parallel; AFAIK there are very few such compilers -I can't name any-, and I am interested by references). Most compilers (and all the one I know) are sequential single-threaded programs.

However, you should define and care about internal intermediate representations and how your compiler is transforming them. You really should read the latest purple [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools#Second_edition) qnd Queinnec's [Lisp In Small Pieces](https://pages.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) (focused on interpreting & compiling Lisp dialects such as Scheme, but you can adapt to your programming language most of the techniques there). Remember that a programming language is some *specification* written in some report, and do not confuse that with an implementation (e.g. some compiler or interpreter).

Most compilers have three parts or layers (with the middle one being the biggest; in [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) it is larger than the front-end & back-end combined!):

- the "front-end" or [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) is taking some source text, and build some *internal representation* called [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST). This an easy and well understood part, you'll just use standard parsing techniques (e.g. a parser generator like ANTLR or flex+bison). Some compilers (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) have *several* front-ends because they are able to compile *several* programming languages (e.g. C, C++, Fortran, Ada, .. for GCC) and they basically (sort-of) define a *common* AST type for all the languages they can accept (in [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), it is called [GENERIC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GENERIC.html))
- the "middle-end" is *transforming* some  *internal representations* (IR), starting from the AST produced by the front-end. In the simplest cases, you just transform an AST into another one to perform very simple transformations (e.g. [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding)). In other compilers, you want some [A-normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-normal_form) as *some* IR (because precise [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) techniques mandates some A-NF), or you use [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). Most C compilers would transform `for` into a `while`-like IR (because the C standard mandates such an equivalence). In more serious [optimizing compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler), you have several different internal representations (some are tree-like like ASTs, others could be [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) or even cyclic graphs) and many dozens or even hundreds of passes which are transforming various internal representations. In many compilers, some [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) form is very useful at some point. [Type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) can be seen as an internal representation transformation. In GCC, an important family of internal representation is the [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) (which is the *same* IR for all source languages accepted by GCC, and on which most optimization passes are operating).
- the "back-end" (or code-generator) is transforming some kind of low-level IR inside the middle-end into some linear representation, like byte code, machine code, or assembler. BTW, GCC has one back-end per target processor (starting with some Gimple/SSA form). In some cases, a back-end contains target-specific optimization transformations. In GCC, [register allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation) and [instruction scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_scheduling) happens in the back-end, and [RTL](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/RTL.html) is a back-end specific (so target specific) representation useful in the back-ends.

AFAIK, many bytecode compilers (notably [`ocamlc`](http://ocaml.org/) & `javac`, but also [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) producing [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) bytecode) have a similar structure; they do have some middle-end (which performs some *simple* "optimizations").

If you are a user of `gcc`, you should try once to compile some simple (but not too simple, you want loops and calls in it) source file `simple.c` as `gcc -fdump-tree-all -c -Wall -O simple.c` and you'll see many dump files `simple.c.*` showing some textual *incomplete* representation of the involved internal representations. You can look into these dump files with a pager (`less`) or some editor. You'll be frightened and surprised by the amount and variety of compiler passes and internal representations.

If you want more pictures about that related to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), look also into the slides I wrote in the [documentation](http://gcc-melt.org/docum.html) part of [GCC-MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (which has a lot of external references too).

Even a very simple bytecode compiler should have some middle-end (at least for constant folding, and also for type inference if your language has some, and probably for some kind of "normalization" -e.g. [A-NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-normal_form) could be useful if you have a "stack" bytecode à la [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) or [Neko](http://nekovm.org/) or [Lua](http://lua.org/)- depending on the bytecode form) and should define some internal representation[s] (probably some AST at least) before transforming it into bytecode (in your "back-end").

BTW, you might perhaps focus only on coding your compiler, and use some *existing* bytecode (e.g. [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), [Neko](http://nekovm.org/), [Lua](http://lua.org/), [Parrot](http://parrot.org/), [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), [Guile2](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Bytecode-and-Objcode.html) ...) instead of designing your own. You could also use some *existing* [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library, e.g. [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), the [libLLVM](http://llvm.org/), [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit), [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), etc... since JIT libraries are conceptually similar to some kind of "bytecode" (they implicitly offer some kind of "back-end" representation thru their API). You could [compile to a subset of C](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257868/when-does-it-make-sense-to-compile-my-own-language-to-c-code-first/257873#257873), i.e. view (some subset of) C as a sort of bytecode (or compile to some existing programming language with a good enough implementation). You probably should care about [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) (the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/) is a useful book to read) and you should probably use or take inspiration from some existing one (e.g. [Boehm's GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/), Ravenbrook's [MPS](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps), or my unmaintained [Qish](http://starynkevitch.net/basile/qishintro.html), or those inside many existing bytecode [VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine)s, sometimes called [P-code machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-code_machine)). Knowing a tiny bit about [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) & [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s should help. You might need [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/).

I do recommend studying the source code of some existing small compiler & bytecode [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) implementation before starting your own.

> If I do compiler -> intermediate language -> bytecode - it should be simpler

Indeed, but don't think or speak of intermediate *language* but simply of **intermediate internal *representations***; you generally don't need these to be a "language", and you probably don't want them to be *easily* "[serializable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)" (there are good reasons to serialize the IR of a compiler -e.g. [`-flto`](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization) in GCC-, but that is *not* trivial and is a transformation by itself).
And the internal representations are often not "trees" but some much more complex data structures (probably with circularities, e.g. related to [cross-references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-reference) and/or symbol tables - which are part of the internal representations).

Notice that bytecode compilers are still compilers, and most of the knowledge is common to compilers generating machine code (since a bytecode is some kind of simple abstract and idealized [instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set)). The main difference is that a bytecode compiler usually won't do any kind of back-end optimization (such as those required by and provided or related to register allocation & instruction scheduling).

<sup>(I did mention several free software implementations above, actually most of the above-mentioned code is free software)</sup>