# Type-based memory safety without manual memory manage or runtime garbage collection?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, language-features

Let's say we wanted a typeful, pure functional programming language, like Haskell or Idris, that is aimed at systems programming without garbage collection and has no runtime (or at least not more than the C and Rust "runtimes"). Something that can run, more or less, on bare metal.

What are some of the options for static memory safety that don't require manual memory management or runtime garbage collection, and how might the problem be solved using the type system of a pure functional similar to Haskell or Idris?

Comment: Anything is *possible,* given enough time, effort and money.  What you *probably* want is a *practical* way to write code without having to worry about memory management.  One way to do that is to stand up your logic in a *process.*  When you're done with your computations, just dump the process, and the operating system will reclaim the memory.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, if it's as easy as just segregating everything into discrete processes (I assume this would be like an OS thread or something), why isn't that the current paradigm? Are there other costs or tradeoffs?

Comment: @chsm: questions starting with "is is possible" are regularly closed on this site, since the only sensible answer to them is "yes". I took the freedom and revised your question, please check if I got you right.

Comment: To me, what you are describing looks pretty mich like what Rust is doing. Could you elaborate in what way Rusts' model differs from what you have in mind?

Comment: @chsm - the tradeoff in Robert Harvey's suggestion is that you need enough (virtual) memory to cover all memory that will be used in each process, and if you don't have enough *physical* memory, some temporary calculations will get paged out to disk needlessly.  This can be mitigated by keeping each process small, which also helps with making them more concurrent, but it's not an easy model to program with IMO.

Comment: @Teimpz - while I obviously can't speak for chsm, I'd say that Rust's model is somewhat lower-level than the kind of language described.  Haskell and Idris are both very high level languages, and the implication is that to do this with a language similar to those, the necessary type information would need to inferred from context rather than explicitly annotated.

Comment: @chsm: The overhead is rather high, which is why you usually do memory management in the programming language instead.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, makes sense.

Comment: @Jules, Haskell doesn't rely _solely_ on type inference; type annotations are allowed and considered best practice for function definitions. I assume Idris is the same, though I'm not as familiar. I included it simply as an example of a language with a stronger type system in case it couldn't be done with simple types.

Comment: @Teimpz, I'm not that familiar with exactly how Rust implements its memory management model, but my first impression is that it is through additional compiler machinery, and not through the type/traits system, since docs mention an "ownership/borrow checker".

Comment: @DocBrown, thanks for fixing the question. Still getting the hang of the various conventions and rules here.

Comment: @chsm: asking questions for which the only reasonable answer is "yes it is possible" is nowhere a good idea, neither on this site, nor on other sites, nor in real life. This has nothing to do with the conventions here ;-)

Comment: @chsm another reason for closing your question is that, if you ask a deep question (such as this one), you (the question asker) are expected to do deep research before asking. This is to prevent others from pointing out too many knowledge gaps between you and the ideal answer to your question. (Knowledge gaps always exist, but when the gap is too large, answers will inevitably evolve into encyclopedic articles.)

Answer (score 4):

Notice [memory management](http://www.memorymanagement.org/) is either explicit and manual (like in hand-written C code), or garbage collected, or ownership based. Read the [*GC handbook*](http://gchandbook.org/) (or at least Paul Wilson's survey on [*Uniprocessor Garbage Collection Techniques*](https://www3.nd.edu/~dthain/courses/cse40243/spring2006/gc-survey.pdf)). Be aware that GC can be quite efficient (read the disputed but interesting old Appel's paper: [*Garbage Collection can be faster than Stack Allocation*](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=31085))

<sup>(notice that garbage collection is a vague concept; it is often defined as any kind of *automatic* memory management technique, including automatic reference counting, tracing or moving GC, etc...)</sup>

Did you look into many implementations of *existing* functional programming languages compiled to C? Some of them use clever techniques, e.g. [Chicken Scheme](https://www.call-cc.org/) (read about [Cheney on the MTA](http://home.pipeline.com/~hbaker1/CheneyMTA.html))

My feeling is that higher-order functional programming requires something close to garbage collection (because closures can outlive their lexical scope).

Perhaps you might google for compile-time garbage collection (and region-based garbage collection).

Maybe you want a functional programming language in which the GC is written -actually the GC would be written in a subset of that language which don't do much allocation-, but that is a different question (e.g. look into the PreScheme dialect inside [Scheme48](http://www.s48.org/)).

Notice that in practice, C standard `malloc` does *not* run on the bare metal (but above some [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)). It is usually built above [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) handling and growing the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (e.g. [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) etc... on Linux). If you are unfamiliar with OS concepts, read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

BTW, you could consider compiling your language [to C](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) and using *existing* garbage collectors (e.g. [MPS](https://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/), [Boehm](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/), ....); or you could consider compiling your language to machine code, but use existing system calls (look into [Bones](http://www.call-with-current-continuation.org/bones/) as an interesting example of Scheme implementation which does not depend on C, not even on the C standard library).

See also Jeremie Salvucci & E.Chailloux paper [*Memory consumption analysis for a functional
and imperative language*](ftp://ftp-sop.inria.fr/indes/TFP15/TFP2015_submission_21.pdf)

Comment: I don't know very much about garbage collection in general; it's something I'm just beginning to learn about. Do you know if the Rust ownership model requires some sort of "compile time" garbage collection? I have a hard time imagining how such "garbage collection" can even work without knowledge of the in-memory values at runtime. I will look into Chicken Scheme.

I'm most interested in approaches to memory management that have no more runtime overhead than the C approach but are not manual. Some sort of abstraction that can be statically checked. The point is to avoid GC altogether.

Comment: But why do you avoid GC, and why do you believe it is better to avoid it? And how would you allocate and manage dynamic (heap) memory? You definitely should read a lot more about GC.

Comment: And you are naive in thinking that C `malloc` & `free` has no runtime overhead. It is actually quite slow w.r.t. to modern GC techniques.

Comment: I suppose this question originates from having a desire for a Haskell-like language that can be used in highly constrained environments (embedded systems, device drivers, etc.) where the overhead of a runtime garbage collector is unattractive. Thank you for the incredible list of resources and further reading, this is a really well-researched answer.

Comment: But your vision of the "overhead of runtime GC" is really naive.

Comment: I don't understand if you want to write a theoretical paper about some form of "compile-time GC" or if you want to implement an *efficient* functional language. For the later, you'll probably need an *efficient GC* (this is really difficult and could take years).

Comment: I would not be surprised to learn that I am naïve about most things. To me garbage collectors seem like a really ad-hoc kind of ugly solution in the first place. It's sort of like "we language designers couldn't imagine a better way to manage memory than doing it manually, so here's this silly add-on that your system has to keep alive to keep track of everything and prevent leaks and segfaults and [...whatever other memory errors exist...]".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72005/discussion-between-basile-starynkevitch-and-chsm).

Answer (score 0):

One other scheme I've seen used that's fairly interesting in this aspect is [Swift and Objective-C's Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

If you're not familiar with it, reference counting is a method where each object has some state (so possibly not suitable for functional programming - I'm not really sure) that keeps track of how many other objects are using it. With manual reference counting, when you allocate a new object, the object has a reference count of 1. If another object wants to use that object, they will call a "retain" method on the object and that will increment the reference count. When they are done, they call "release" and the reference count goes down. When the reference count hits 0, the object deletes itself.

That's manual reference counting. With automatic reference counting, the developer never explicitly retains or releases anything. The compiler handles all the details of that for you. You simply allocate an object and then, as if by magic, when you are done using it, it is freed. The magic is that the compiler notices when you do things like assignments and calls retain and release for you. This does involve some additional annotations in the code so that the compiler can understand how an object is going to be used. So you might mark a value you're going to hold on to as "strong" and one that you use but don't own as "weak", for example. Due to mostly sensible defaults, you don't need to annotate most values, as the defaults are what you want.

It's been suggested that this is similar to garbage collection. I disagree. For example, the [Wikipedia article on ARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting) says:

> ARC differs from tracing garbage collection in that there is no background process that deallocates the objects asynchronously at runtime.

When doing manual reference counting, you often have an autorelease pool, so you never go more than 1 event loop without cleaning up, and in fact you can create an autorelease pool at any time with any scope you wish, so it's controlled by the developer. It doesn't happen at some unknown future time that might interrupt other work. Also, when done automatically, it's not at all like garbage collection. As I understand it, the freeing of memory will happen immediately when, for example, you assign a pointer from an old object to a new object. That's very different from a garbage collector that periodically does a cleanup, and much closer to manually handling resources via things like `malloc` and `free`. In my experience the performance implications of reference counting, particularly automatic reference counting, are better than and more predictable than garbage collection. But I admit I've not done much with garbage collection.

Comment: Automatic reference counting is, IMHO, a form of garbage collection. It deals poorly with [circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference).

Comment: I've amended my answer to address your concern.

Comment: Many books present ARC as a form of GC. You could disagree, but it is an established position (with which I personally agree). The point is that GC is a quite vague concept (and might have different definitions). Your description of GC is just one technique among other GC techniques.

Comment: @user1118321, cf. also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)#Strategies

Comment: "ARC differs from tracing garbage collection in that there is no background process that deallocates the objects asynchronously at runtime" does not state that ARC _is not_ garbage collection, only that it differs from _tracing_ garbage collection strategies.

Comment: Fair point. Regardless, its characteristics differ enough from traditional garbage collection that it's worth considering it. It's basically just the compiler inserting the equivalent of `malloc` and `free` into your code for you.

Comment: @user1118321: I don't think it makes sense of speaking of "traditional garbage collection". There are many GC techniques (one of them being ARC), but I don't think that one is more traditional than others. Likewise, there are many kind of databases, but I won't call RDBMS "traditional databases", even if they are common.